# Can data between android devices be sent just using the phone operating company?

Tags: android, telecommunication

By using just the phone operating company I'm meaning a situation like this:

When you do a phone call, it looks like the only action that happens is "only" the phone call being received by the phone operating company and then it redirects the phone call to the called number so the communication can be stablished.

I think something similar should be possible with sent data, you just send the data with a format that indicates in a similar way that it's trying to connect with another phone, expect it to be received by the phone operating company and have it delivered to that phone.

I know technologies are far from being the same but I think that the comparison still applies.

From what I've read here it looks like it's not possible to do something like that, whatever the case you are going to need a server on the internet that deals with that be it directly or indirectly. Looks like my best option would be using something like PubNub, anyway it looks that it hasn't been explicitly determined that something like that cannot be done, also answers related to sending data between devices were a bit old, so just in case I'd like to know if that's possible.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Data sent between devices needs to use some transport and addressing mechanism and as I am sure you are aware the most common approach these days is to use the IP protocol.

This is a separate protocol stack than the traditional telephony protocol stack and it uses different addressing - the phone number which is uniquely mapped to your phone in the Android world is not a valid form of address in the IP world.

To allow you send data using the telephone number as the destination address you would need a mapping between telephone numbers and IP addresses. You would also need some way to indicate to the receiving device what application should receive the data - the same function the port number provides in the IP stack.

There is nothing to stop you building such a mapping, and, in fact, such mappings do exist in the Voice over IP world (VoIP) for example where a phone number will be translated to an IP address of a destination device.

However, these approaches still require a 'server' to do the mapping between address schemes which I think you are trying to avoid.

The closest thing in the traditional telephony world to what you outline might be SMS, which will send sets of text 'data' directly between SMS capable phones, but I don't think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid having to do one myself, that's right, but my question is about if the phone operating company server could do that automatically, I mean I guess for them it's almost the same receiving a request that redirects the data to a web server, so you get the web page on your phone, than receiving a request to send the data to a mobile phone number, they can have mapped the corresponding ip and send the data as is. You cannot ask for the company to have the data for the applications you use, but allowing that service doesn't look like too much to ask.

Comment: In traditional telephony networks the connection that receives signalling for a voice call would not be able to receive IP packet like data. In more recent networks which use SIP or similar signalling over IP networks, then they could implement a protocol on top of IP which allowed you use a telephone number as an address. They would still need something in the background to map from the telephone number to an IP address. I think the key question is what the use case or driver would be for them to offer a service like this, given it could be done independently anyway?